# imported data to gephi is always a string

Tags: python, graph, networkx, gephi

I'm importing a .gml file into Gephi, that I build using the python module networkx.  All of my node attributes and labels are imported as strings instead of floats, which is messing up several things (using node attributes for visuals, and accessing the list of nodes in the scripting console).  Is there any way to import data the correct way?  Will it change anything to import to Gephi as a different graph format?  I'm doing this with an eye to programmatically drawing graphs in Gephi.  Thanks!

Comment: Importing a .gexf file renders the node attributes in the correct way, but node id is still a string.

Comment: On the .gexf import, node id that are a "float", i.e. "23.0", are converted to string, but "23" is imported as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try including the ID as an attribute. Thats simpler way of solving this (I think).

Regards,

George G. Vega

(author of the R package "rgexf")

http://ggvega.com